# php run script that needs X windows

Tags: php, apache, x11

I want to run an bash script from PHP on Apache server that needs X windows to run correctly.
any body has any idea how can i do that?

BTW currently i'm using a desktop version of ubuntu as server but i'm also plan to switch to a server version and use Xvfb as X server.

Thanks.

Comment: We need more information on why it needs X-Windows. Whyt libraries are you using and what commands require a running X session?

Comment: the app i'm gonna run is firefox.

Comment: Are you sure you are not just opening a local URL to a php file with your firefox? Are you really trying to access firefox functions directly from within a php script? This sounds a bit odd.